# Flutter simple marquee widget and getting ScrollController not attached to any scroll views error

Tags: flutter

this below simple widget is used in my application for making simple marquee text into another widgets for `Text`, in that when text length is too short i get this error:

```
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views error
```

my problem is know how can i calculate text length in dynamic with and avoid throwing this error?

for example:

```
MarqueeWidget(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Text(
      '$parsedString', //-> text length is not known
    style: AppTheme.of(context).caption(
  ),
),
```

and this is `MarqueeWidget` which i used from it

```
class MarqueeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Axis direction;
  final Duration animationDuration, backDuration, pauseDuration;

  MarqueeWidget({
    @required this.child,
    this.direction: Axis.horizontal,
    this.animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 7000),
    this.backDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    this.pauseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
  });

  @override
  _MarqueeWidgetState createState() => _MarqueeWidgetState();
}

class _MarqueeWidgetState extends State<MarqueeWidget> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    try{
      scroll();
    }catch(error){

    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: widget.child,
      scrollDirection: widget.direction,
      controller: scrollController,
    );
  }

  void scroll() async {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(widget.pauseDuration);
      await scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: widget.animationDuration,
          curve: Curves.easeIn);
      await Future.delayed(widget.pauseDuration);
      await scrollController.animateTo(0.0,
          duration: widget.backDuration, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try using `TextPainter` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as follow,

```
    @override
      void initState() {
           WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
           try {
               scroll();
           } catch (error){
               // log error
           }
    });
}
```

> WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() method gets called once the build() method gets rendered.

The error in your case is you are calling scroll() method which tries to scroll using scrollController which might be called before the build method gets executed.

Comment: Thanks to reply to my question, this problem is shown again

Comment: also, remove the line await Future.delayed(widget.pauseDuration);